# How to instantiate an Octave classdef object in C++ and call its methods

Tags: c++, octave

I know how to call a function defined in an .m-file using the Octave interpreter and `feval` as shown [in the Octave manual](https://octave.org/doc/v6.3.0/Standalone-Programs.html#Standalone-Programs) but not how to do something similar using Octave classes and their methods.

If I have a simple class defined in Octave using the classdef method such as

```
classdef TestClass < handle
  properties
    val
  endproperties
  methods
    function obj = TestClass()
      obj.val = 1;
    endfunction 
    function obj = setval(obj, v)
      obj.val = v;
    endfunction
    function showval(obj)
      disp(obj.val);
    endfunction  
  endmethods
endclassdef
```

If I then would would like to use my class in some C++ code, how would I go about doing that. In Octave it would be:

```
c = TestClass(); //create an instance of TestClass
c.setval(100); //use the objects methods
c.showval(); //display 100
```

### Solution

Based on the answer below I'll present my solution here. The above octave code can be rewritten as

```
c = TestClass();
setval(c, 100);
showval(c);
```

which can be turned into this C++ code

```
#include <interpreter.h>
#include <parse.h>

int main()
{
    octave::interpreter interpreter;
    interpreter.execute();

    octave_value_list arg;
    octave_value c;
    
    c = octave::feval("TestClass", arg, 1).xelem(0);     

    arg(0) = c; 
    arg(1) = 100;
    octave::feval("setval", arg);  

    arg.clear(); 
    arg(0) = c;
    octave::feval("showval", arg);  

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already know how to call an Octave function from C++, then all you are missing is that `a.b()` is the same as `b(a)`. Calling a method is just like calling a function, there is no distinction. Octave figures out which overload of the function to call based on the input arguments.

The bit of Octave code you posted,

```matlab
c = TestClass();
c.setval(100);
c.showval();
```

can also be written as

```matlab
c = TestClass();
setval(c, 100);
showval(c);
```